# EMR 5.21 , Spark 2.4 - Json4s Dependency broken

Tags: amazon-web-services, apache-spark, amazon-emr, json4s

## Issue

In EMR 5.21 , Spark - Hbase integration is broken.
df.write.options().format().save() fails.
Reason is  json4s-jackson version 3.5.3 in spark 2.4 , EMR 5.21 
it works fine in EMR 5.11.2 , Spark 2.2  , son4s-jackson version 3.2.11 
Problem is this is EMR so i cant rebuild spark with lower json4s . 
is there any workaround ?

## Error

py4j.protocol.Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling o104.save. : java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.json4s.jackson.JsonMethods$.parse(Lorg/json4s/JsonInput;Z)Lorg/json4s/JsonAST$JValue;

## Submission

```
spark-submit --master yarn \
--jars /usr/lib/hbase/  \
--packages com.hortonworks:shc-core:1.1.3-2.3-s_2.11 \
--repositories http://repo.hortonworks.com/content/groups/public/  \
pysparkhbase_V1.1.py s3://<bucket>/ <Namespace> <Table> <cf> <Key>
```

## Code

```
import sys
from pyspark.sql.functions import concat
from pyspark import SparkContext
from pyspark.sql import SQLContext,SparkSession
spark = SparkSession.builder.master("yarn").appName("PysparkHbaseConnection").config("spark.some.config.option", "PyHbase").getOrCreate()
spark.sql("set spark.sql.parquet.compression.codec=uncompressed")
spark.conf.set("spark.serializer", "org.apache.spark.serializer.KryoSerializer");
data_source_format = 'org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.hbase'
df = spark.read.parquet(file)
df.createOrReplaceTempView("view")
.
cat = '{|"table":{"namespace":"' + namespace + '", "name":"' + name + '", "tableCoder":"' + tableCoder + '", "version":"' + version + '"}, \n|"rowkey":"' + rowkey + '", \n|"columns":{'
.
df.write.options(catalog=cat).format(data_source_format).save()
```

Answer (score 0):

There's no obvious answer. A quick check of [the SHC POM](https://github.com/hortonworks-spark/shc/blob/master/pom.xml) doesn't show a direct import of the json file, so you can't just change that pom & build the artifact yourself.

You're going to have to talk to the EMR team to get them to build the connector & HBase in sync.

FWIW, getting jackson in sync is one of the stress point of releasing a big data stack, and the AWS SDK's habit of updating their requirements on their fortnightly release one of the stress points ... Hadoop moved to the aws shaded SDK purely to stop the AWS engineering decisions defining the choices for everyone.

Comment: json4s is a dependency of spark not SHC
https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/master/pom.xml
similar issue https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48357604/spark-2-2-cannot-write-df-to-parquet

Comment: Is there any alternative way of pushing spark dataframe in hbase ??

Comment: Out of my depth there, I'm afraid

Answer (score 0):

downgrade json4s to 3.2.10 can resolve it. but I think it's SHC bug,need to upgrade it.